# linux mint - loud system beep on laptop

Tags: linux-mint

I installed the newest Linux mint on My BTO W271EU laptop. All Works well, for a couple of minutes.

Then the system beeps start. Really loud and continuously. Other symptoms are a flashing caps Lock and num Lock light. After a few minutes the PC shuts down. Without warning.

This occurs after 5 minutes. Sometimes after An hour An sometimes I can use My laptop for Days without It happening.

I already disabled the pcspkr. And added It To the blacklist (as found on mighty Google). But that doesn't work.

### edit:

I also noticed that when the Laptop starte beeping and shut it self down. The beeping also occurs on startup. Once the kernel is loaded it starts beeping continiously. Again untill it shuts itself down.

I have the problem with power cord plugged in and plugged out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried following these instructions? http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1116

Comment: When the beebs start, type `dmesg` to see if there is any relevant messages.  One idea could be that your computer is over heating.

Comment: I tried the First link. Nothing. The laptop isnt overheating.

Comment: I did some tests wtith overheating. After some stress tests tem went up to 70C but no beep. then later on I was browsing the internet (temp was around 40C) and it started beepding again

Comment: This is probably something you already did, but have you checked the condition of your Harddrive?

Comment: The laptop is 3 weeks old. So everything should be ok. And it's an SSD